# IstioIngressGateway and Virtual Service with custom TCP Ports

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, istio, tcpportsharing

IstioIngressGateway and Virtual Service with custom TCP Ports.

I have deployed my TCP Server as service in my Azure Kubernetes Cluster.

I have downloaded the istio package. I have modifed the `install\kubernetes\helm\istio\values-istio-gateways.yaml` with my TCP ports. And then i have deployed the istio under istio-system namespace. All the services are up and running.

**issue#1:** Under istio-ingressgateway service, i don't see my custom TCP ports.

**issue#2:** Since i don't see my TCP ports,I have modified the istio-ingressgateway service using the command - (`kubectl edit svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system`), and i have added my ports. I have created the Virtual Service, by adding the source port/Host and destination port(my TCP service port). When i try to access the istiogateway with my tcp ports, i am unable to hit. I see that i can hit the default https ports like 80 and 443. I tried from the TCP client and and also from curl command.

Please anyone can answer my question, what could be the reason, and if you know any solution for this issue let me know.

Comment: can you add your `Gateway` and `VirtualService` yamls? Also, what are the modifications you did on `istio-ingressgateway` service?

Comment: Hi, what version of helm and istio are you using?